# Add class to active list item in jquery

Tags: php, css

I have list in foreach loop in Php as like below

```
<?php 
     $cnt=1;
     foreach ($this->session->userdata('questions') as $row) {
         $i=1;
         foreach($row as $q) {      ?>
           <li id="<?php echo "number-". $q->subjectid."_".$i;?>" onclick="showQuestion('<?php echo "#".$q->subjectid."_".$i;?>');" class="btn bg-primary numbers z-answered"  >
            <?php echo $cnt++;?>
            </li>
            <?php 
            $i++;
         } 
    } 
?>
```

It will show question numbers from 1 to 100 (assume)

I want When a user will click any question, It will add demo css class to current question
How to achieve it.

Comment: have you tried .addClass()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery for the purpose if you want to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('demo');
    //code to remove class from rest of the <li>'s
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('demo');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. Can u tell me how to remove this class after unclicking that list. Means When i click on another question, This class will remove from that list and add to current list

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `addClass()` method.